# Why is cond function not printing in scheme?

Tags: function, conditional-statements, scheme, racket

I am very new to scheme, and I am having trouble getting simple cond functions that I make to print in DrRacket ide. When I run these two functions:

```
(define (test x)
  (cond
   [(zero? x) (error "doesn't get here, either")]
   [(positive? x) 'here]))

(define (compare x y)
  (cond [(equal? x y) "Is Equal"]))
```

it prints:

```
> test 12
#<procedure:test>
12
> compare 12 12
#<procedure:compare>
12
12
```

Why will it not output any of the errors, or "Is Equal"? It works fine if I run the cond statements directly and replace the variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not actually *calling* the new procedures, you must surround the procedure name and its arguments between brackets `()`, just as you did with all the other procedures you're using in your solution! This is the way:

```
(test 12)
=> 'here

(compare 12 12)
=> "Is Equal"
```